# What do I call a constant with the value 1.9999

Tags: java, c++, naming-conventions

I have a class for numbers, FixedDecimal.

For it I have a test. I run the test with several values; 1, 1.9, 1.99, 1.999, 1.9999.

I'd like named constants for these.

What should I call them?

```
FixedDecimal _1_ = new FixedDecimal(1, 1);
FixedDecimal _1_9 = new FixedDecimal(19, 10);
FixedDecimal _1_99 = new FixedDecimal(199, 100);
FixedDecimal _1_999 = new FixedDecimal(1999, 1000);
FixedDecimal _1_9999 = new FixedDecimal(19999, 10000);
```

It looks slightly unintuitive. Is there another character than underscore (_) that I can use?

Comment: naming a constant after its value is senseless, it might as well be a literal. Name it after its usage.

Comment: ...or don't name it at all and just use the numeric literal.

Comment: agreed with @Jodrell it's meaningless to name it like that...

Comment: This reminds me of an april fools joke I did sometime: `#define ONE 1`, `#define TWO 2`, etc. Very useful for whenever the value of `ONE` has to be redefined to another value someday! ;-)

Comment: If it is a dollar amount then $1234 is a valid identifier.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of test values?

Comment: @JeffFoster - `$` is not a valid character for an identifier in standard C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker true, did not see it was tagged C++ as well as Java

Comment: @JeffFoster - I hadn't noticed that it was tagged Java. Fortunately, I wrote the comment so that it came out right; there are C and C++ implementations that allow `$`.

Answer (score 5):

If the name of your constant reflects a numeric representation of the constant, you're doing it wrong.

Good constants:

```
BOILING_C = 100
BOILING_F = 212
TUESDAY = 2
```

Bad constants:

```
_100 = 100
_212 = 212
//What would you put for Tuesday anyway?
```

You should probably just use the values directly.

Comment: I realize I should have put more text in my example, but then you could've assumed I was not an idiot. :-) Voted -1.

Comment: @RogerWernersson I didn't assume anything about you. I provided a good example in my answer that would help other users who might see this Q/A as well as help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using concrete Unitname will help.

```
FixedDecimal _1 = new FixedDecimal(1, 1);
FixedDecimal _19deci = new FixedDecimal(19, 10);
FixedDecimal _199centi = new FixedDecimal(199, 100);
FixedDecimal _1999mili = new FixedDecimal(1999, 1000);
FixedDecimal _19999micro = new FixedDecimal(19999, 10000);
```

Regards

Comment: _19deci is better than _19000micro because they are not the same thing. The former has one decimal and the latter four.

Comment: Trailing zeros are by convention only significant in decimal numbers, not integers...

Comment: No, it has 1 digit of significance by the convention I learnt: I also was taught that using "number of digits" as "digits of significance" is sloppy, and you should instead carry around explicit error bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers as to practices about constant naming are absolutely correct, an answer for you question is: you can use $ instead of _ in this case.

Comment: `$` is not a valid character for an identifier in standard C++.

Comment: The question is tagged for **both** C++ and Java.

Comment: Although it's not necessarily clear if the intention is for AND whether OR.

Comment: I'm confused. Which part of "`$` is not a valid character for an identifier in standard C++" are you talking about? It's a simple statement, and correct.

Comment: I'm not talking about your statement, I'm talking about author's intention of putting multiple tags to a question and whether he means conjunction or disjunction of these tags. In other words: "java" && "c++" && "naming-conventions" or ("java" || "c++") && "naming-conventions". Anyway --- I see no point in developing of this thread, have a nice day.